# Some UI parts do not respond

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Some, but not all UI Components are not responding.

Restart, rebuild code and clean caches.

Part of the template file

```java
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">JKPGBooking /.::.\ Boka online på ED</ui:insert></title>

    </h:head>



    <h:body>

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">

            <ui:insert name="menu">
                <ui:include
                    src="/WEB-INF/template/header_#{userbean.currUser.role}.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </ui:insert>
            <p:spacer style="width: 100px; height: 10px;"></p:spacer>
            <ui:insert name="content_row1_col2" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <ui:insert name="content_row2_col1">

        </ui:insert>



        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:insert>

    </h:body>

    </html>
```

part of the .xhtml

```html
    <ui:define name="content_row1_col2">
                <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <p:panelGrid columns="5" id="userform">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Vem har bokat salen?" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="vecka" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{infobean.week}" autoWidth="true" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{infobean.allWeeks}" >
                            </f:selectItems>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <h:outputText value="Dag" />

                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{infobean.day}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{infobean.days}">
                            </f:selectItems>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <h:commandButton value="Sök"
                            action="#{infobean.getHouseSchedule}" update="resultTab">
                            </h:commandButton>

                    </p:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
                </ui:define>
```

Everything renders nicely but in this case only the button of the form is responding will says is fired. If I enlarge the page in the browser by changing the zoom the SelectOneMenu for the day is responding too, but never the the SelectOneMenu for the week.  If I remove the panelGrid the form works as intended.

this is one example of the problem. On another page are tabs generatered by a script, in most cases 12-14. Often the last two or three are not responding/firing and there is no mouseover/hiver response. What really fiddles me is that is not always the case.

Comment: Hi. `h:commandButton` will not work with the `update` attribute - that attribute is PrimeFaces-specific. There might also be something from the enclosing template interfering with your page. Without seeing more, this is just a guess though. Which JSF version and implementation are you under?

Comment: I use JSF 2.2.9/Primefaces 6.2. The buttons works as intended, method is fired, table updated. But I can't change the week on the SelectOneMenu. No pulldown, no mouseOver/Hover effect. Works if i delete the PanelGrid tags in the template.

Comment: First of, change to `p:commanButton`. If that doesn't improve things, show us the whole template also.

Comment: Edit: Check question for the whole template

Comment: So you are currently mixing use of `h:panelGrid` with `p:panelGrid` ... What happens if you just keep to using one of them? While it always constantly gets better - PrimeFaces can sometimes mess up the generated page when mixing components like that.

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that even if its being updated when the button is pressed, your current code is doing a full page update instead of an AJAX update -  which I'm guessing was your intention? If you want an AJAX update with `h:commandButton`you need to use an `f:ajax` tag.

Comment: Still the same behavior and the full refresh is intended.

Comment: Then get rid of the `update=` attribute ;), because that doesn't make any sense. My next suggestion is to make a [mcve]. Maybe even remove the template and see if it *still* behaves the same. I can try to reproduce it later.

Comment: Better hints how to correctly create a "minimal reproducible example" specifically for JSF can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info